# Cloth Stimulation Not Working (Blender Not Responding)

Tags: cloth-simulation

I am much new to Blender. I have been following several tutorials online about Cloth Stimulation, and I have followed exactly the same procedure but mine Blender freezes during Cloth Stimulation, and I have to force close Blender and reopen.

I have tried it 20-30 times but no luck. Could it be because of my laptop harware? I use a Sony Vaio i5 processor, 6 GB RAM and NVIDIA GeForce 410M. My laptop may not have best hardware but never had this problem even while using Unity.

I am using Blender 2.90.1

Please check the raw file. [Blend File](https://www.theappwiz.com/files/latest.blend)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How much RAM(s) do you have? And what's your GPU? I think the cloth simulation is too heavy or something. Mine freezes too, but my RAM doesn't flood or something

Comment: @CikittaTjok thanks, I have 6 GB RAM and NVIDIA GeForce 410M

Comment: Ahh okay.. there must be something wrong. I can't bake the simulation at all, and it stuck on frame 2. Edit: Okay it's baking on frame 3 now. I can say the simulation is too heavy. Another edit: The result is REALLY weird..

Comment: Thanks for trying. As I said I have no idea what's going on, it looked so simple on tutorial. I will wait for someone to help.

Comment: Maybe try re-creating the cloth? It overlaps badly

Comment: Okay, yes I guess I will have to keep trying. As I said I have tried it several times and follow the exact tutorial, I would do no different even if retry.

Comment: Cloth sims are heavy on calculations, more verts is not necessarily better.  You can get something close and then apply subdivisions or go into sculpt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your model is very small. I think that a severe collision has already occurred at the start frame, making it difficult for the calculation to converge. When I increased the size of the model by 10 times, the simulation became much faster.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your response and solution. Its works, didn't know size can do that.

Comment: @Dev Chauhan, If you set the collision parameters to match the size of the polygon, it may work with the original size.